# How can i get dateRange based on month

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, typescript, javascript-objects

I am trying to get the dateRange within a month based on the start of the week in that month to the end of week. So for example, if i pass the month January, 2020, the dateRange should fetch data from [2019-12-30 to 2020-01-31],

February = [2020-02-03 to 2020-02-28], 
March = [2020-03-02 to 2020-04-03]

[image]

Comment: I guess you want end of the month not end of the week.

Comment: i actually want the start of the week and the end of the week...so in 2020, week 1 starts from December 30, 2019 and the end of the week in that month stops at January 31, 2020

Answer (score 3):

I recommend you check moment.js (https://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/week/)

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Kaca992  This was what i got working for me, and it can still be refactored. #MakeThisCodeBetter

```
   function GregorianWeeksInAYear(){

        let year = 2020;
        let month = 0;
        let startDate = "";
        let endDate = "";

         const monthsInYear = [];


      while (month < 12){
       let isLeapYear = moment([year]).isLeapYear();

     if(isLeapYear){
     if(month > 0){
       startDate = moment([year,month]).startOf('month').isoWeekday(1).add(7,'days');

     }
      else{
         startDate = moment([year,month]).startOf('month').isoWeekday(1);

      }

       endDate = 


moment([year,month]).endOf('month').isoWeekday(1).add(5,'days').subtract(1,'days');
     }
       else{
     startDate = moment([year,month]).startOf('month').isoWeekday(1);

    endDate = moment([year,month]).endOf('month').isoWeekday(1).add(4,'days');
    }
       monthsInYear.push({start:moment(startDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD'),end:moment(endDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD'),name: moment(startDate).add(4,'days').format('MMMM')})

   month++;
        }

     return monthsInYear;
          }
```